# TDE csv extract best use

Tags: tableau-api

I'm planning on gathering some older data and consolidating it. These files are all csv broken down daily so there are a ton of them.

1. merge the csv files into one
2. I was thinking of using the tde extract API to only select the columns which are valuable to me
3. I would then use that script moving forward on the daily update files to keep the columns aligned
4. I would then Append my new mini extracts to the large consolidated one
5. (is there a way to create or insert a unique id or primary key during this process so I can do incremental refreshes easily too?)

Is this an efficient way to do things? All of the files I deal with are excel or csv and they are not consolidated automatically.

Comment: I believe there are more easier and efficient ways to perform this outside Tableau. If you intend to use tde extract API, I assume you have some knowledge in some programming language. If you know python, I recommend you learning pandas library (if you don`t know it already). With that you can easily handle those multiple csv files and create a new one (or even export to MySQL, for instance, what would be smarter)

Comment: Python is probably a good way to go for a lot of the input processing and manipulation if you are comfortable with programming. But if your main goal is to analyze the data with Tableau, then generating or appending to an extract at the end of your ETL process still makes sense. Tableau extracts are designed to be very efficient when read by Tableau -- and the data extract API can be called by Python. You could also feed a RDBMS if other tools are involved. If you're not comfortable with programming, you could look at Alteryx or the like for a COTS way to do the same thing.